# How to consider previous month first day and previous month last day in timestamp (13 digits--milliseconds) format in python 2.7 and python 3x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Suppose today is `August 28, 2019` i want `timestamp` of `July 1,12:00:00 AM` and `July 31,23:59:59 PM`. In general, I want the previous month date and time irrespective of year.

Comment: But i want the timestamp should be in 13 digits i mean in millisecond format.Can someone help me to get the data in python 2.7 and python 3x ?

Comment: I want the result in 13 digit Timestamp format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work for both Python 3x and Python2.7

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = date.today()
d = today - relativedelta(months=1)

first_day = date(d.year, d.month, 1)
first_day.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
#returns first date of the previous month - datetime.date(2019, 7, 1)

last_day = date(today.year, today.month, 1) - relativedelta(days=1)
last_day.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')

# returns the last date of the previous month - datetime.date(2019, 7, 31)
```

Note - The above code only returns the first and last date, not the time. I don't really understand why can't you just hard code the time in milliseconds since it will always be fixed, irrespective of the date.

Comment: Spot on. Absolute cracker.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively with no additional modules:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
print(now)
firstOfThisMonth = now.replace(day=1)
print(firstOfThisMonth)
endOfLastMonth = firstOfThisMonth-timedelta(days=1)
print(endOfLastMonth)
firstOfLastMonth = endOfLastMonth.replace(day=1)
print(firstOfLastMonth)
print(firstOfLastMonth.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0))
print(endOfLastMonth.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=0))
```

Outputs the following

```
2019-08-28 07:36:38.768223
2019-08-01 07:36:38.768223
2019-07-31 07:36:38.768223
2019-07-01 07:36:38.768223
2019-07-01 00:00:00
2019-07-31 23:59:59
```